# Kafka Schema Registry - block messages that aren't accepted in the schema registry in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, kafka-rest

I have a schema in kafka and I need that every time I post a post in this topic, the schema that I registered **checks if it is in the same pattern** that is being sent.

My schema is:
[image]

Curl post:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Operacao\",\"namespace\":\"data.brado.operacao\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id_operacao\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"tipo_container\",\"type\":\"string\"}, {\"name\":\"descricao_operacao\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"entrega\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"coleta\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"descricao_checklist\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"cheio\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"ativo\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"tipo_operacao\",\"type\":\"string\"} ]}"}' http://localhost:38081/subjects/teste/versions
```

What I need is that when I make a post in the topic it doesn't allow me to send it if it doesn't have this pattern

I was supposed to accuse an error here, because I'm not sending the right schema
[image]

And it would work in that case[image]

Can anyone help me how to do this check in schema? I've looked everywhere I've found and I haven't found any answers to this.

Comment: I assume you are using the kafka REST proxy, or is it something else? Is that web server actually producing data using Avro producer or just forwarding through the `records` list as JSON/text (therefore ignoring any schema)?

Comment: I'm just forwarding the records as text/json.. if I do it this way, will it ignore the schema registry?

Comment: does my schema registry only work if my producer checks the configured schema first?

so I need to add this validation to my producer?

Comment: if i just post the topic in postman, will it ignore the schema registry?

Answer (score 0):

The schema registry will only block producers that are configured to use it. By default, the broker will not enforce a schema. For that, you need to [pay for Confluent Server](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-validation.html).

Hard to tell what image you are showing (what REST endpoint you are using), but if it is the Confluent Kafka REST Proxy, then refer to quick-start section on [producing and consuming Avro](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/quickstart.html#produce-and-consume-avro-messages).

```bash
# Produce a message using Avro embedded data, including the schema which will
# be registered with schema registry and used to validate and serialize
# before storing the data in Kafka
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json" \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
      --data '{"value_schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"User\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"}]}", "records": [{"value": {"name": "testUser"}}]}' \
      "http://localhost:8082/topics/avrotest"
```

Without these specifics, you're just sending plain-text JSON, which will do no schema checks.

If you have direct access to the Kafka cluster, then writing an Avro producer client would be easier since you don't need to embed the key and/or value schemas every time you want to send an event.

Comment: I'm using confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.0.3.

I have this error when I generate the post as the example. https://prnt.sc/a_kkeZGfQsnV

Do you know what it could be?

Comment: You're using the wrong service. The registry does not accept producer requests. The REST Proxy does. I.e. `confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest` container

Comment: i'm using the cp-schema-registry and the cp-kafka-rest

Comment: to do this curl post i did use the cp-kafka service

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wVBZsMi81p0b

Comment: You need to find the real error from `docker logs schema-registry`, for example

Comment: i did check the logs and don't appear the reason, only the 408 error.. i will open the other question to discute this, thanks for the help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776132/error-when-registering-schema-problem-to-produce-avro-messages-via-kafka-rest