# Error when registering schema. Problem to produce AVRO messages via Kafka REST. Error_code: 40801

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, kafka-rest

I'm following the confluent tutorial to produce messages ([Produce and Consume Avro Messages](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/quickstart.html#)), but when I post in the messages defining the schema registry, it gives the following error and I don't know how to continue, I've looked in several places and none have this error

```json
{
    "error_code": 40801,
    "message": "Error when registering schema. format = AVRO, subject = teste-value, schema = {\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"teste\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"
}
```

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json" \
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
          --data '{"value_schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"teste\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"}]}", "records": [{"value": {"name": "teste"}}]}' \
          "http://localhost:38082/topics/teste"
```

[image]

Comment: What if you follow this page instead? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/rest-proxy.html#produce-avro-records

Comment: now, this error appear

Comment: https://prnt.sc/UwLnKMTzRxPn

Answer (score 0):

Can you try formatting your query like the following and give it a try.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Payment\",\"namespace\":\"io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"double\"}]}"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-value/versions
```

Comment: same error. https://prnt.sc/Ov7ekvLxwm4I

Comment: Looking at the Schema Registry error code, this what it is. 10.4.9 408 Request Timeout : The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time. Can you check your Schema Registry is accepting the request or up and running, doing a simple telnet test or any other means.

Comment: I'm still getting the error, I checked the log and couldn't find the reason for the error